# Trimming a part of file extension for all the files in directory - Linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a requirement in which I want to trim the file extension for all the files contained in a directory: -

The file will be like;

```
America.gz:2170
Europe.gz:2172
Africa.gz:2170
Asia.gz:2172
```

what I need is to trim the :2170 and :2172 from all the files, so that only the .gz extension remains.

I know that with the help of below SED code, it is possible for all the entries in a file, however I need for all the files in a directory: -

```
**sed 's/:.*//' file**
```

Any bash or awk code to fix this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in `bash`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.gz:*; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f%:*}"
done
```

`"${f%:*}"` will remove everything after `:` on RHS of variable `$f`

Comment: Would be perfect with a `shopt -s nullglob`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf do you need to make it `mv -- "$f"...` to make it "perfect" :-) ? I'm really not sure what it'd do as-is with a file whose name starts with `-`.

Comment: Wow, this works like a miracle ! Kudos to Anubhava, Gniourf and Ed.
Can you please help me in understanding the below from the code: -

mv -- "$f" "${f%:*}"

1) why we use --
2) is it mandatory to enclose the variable under double quotes? can't we just use $f instead of "$f"
3) what is the significance of using {}

Guys, I am a true beginner with ZERO programming background, just started to learn bash scripting using YouTube videos and other online sources. Can you please suggest any good source/ link/ pdf/ videos wherein I can start from scratch and finish it off at a good level. Thanks much!

Comment: @user5419230: Keeping argument after `--` tells `mv` that arguments should not be interpreted as options to `mv` command. Quoting variables is a good practice and especially important for filenames as filenames can contains whitespaces or newlines also in Unix. There are so many good tutorials on Unix shell scripting. You can just google it.

Comment: @anubhava
Now I am into another issue. My system has changed the name of the file to as below.

    `SimilarX.LCA}33362}1444572402}0}coll_DefaultColl}`
    `SimilarY.LCA}33362}1444572402}0}coll_DefaultColl}`
    `SimilarZ.LCA}33362}1444572402}0}coll_DefaultColl}`

I want to trim the last so that it became as below: -

    `SimilarX.LCA`
    `SimilarY.LCA`
    `SimilarZ.LCA`

I changed the code to;

#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.AIR}*; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f%(}*)}"
done

However its not working. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: You can use `mv -- "$f" "${f%%}*}"` in above `for` loop for that.

Comment: Thanks much for the help @anubhava
I was not able to test the second problem due to some personal constraints. However I have accepted and rated your first answer. Can you please elaborate that how does this code "${f%%}*}" helps in achieving the requirement?

Comment: It is because `"${f%%}*}"` will remove the longest part in `$f` starting from `}`. Check `man bash` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may use rename command.

```
rename 's/:.*//' *.gz:*
```

or

```
rename 's/:[^:]*$//' *.gz:*
```

Comment: This would be dangerous for a file named `hello:how:are:you.gz:1234`.

Answer (score 0):

This entire job can be done with a `for` loop and the substring processing operator '%':

"${parameter%word}     Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern."

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in *
do #mv "$i" "${i%:}"
   echo " mv $i ${i%:*}"
done
```